# CSS3 PIE with COMPASS in RAILS app

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, compass-sass, css3pie

I need CSS3 in IE 8 so I think I need PIE to create css3 "functions" in IE8. How can I simple integrate it to my design. I have a lot of border-radius and other css3 efects.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Compass documentation](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/pie/).

> > compass install compass/pie
> >
> > This will install an example stylesheet and a PIE.htc behavior file that must be loaded into your pages for IE.

Comment: I tried it but I have this error: 
"No application integration exists for rails"

Comment: Sounds like this page will help: https://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/browse_thread/thread/5064e92d13285289

Comment: thank you, I ran this "bundle exec compass install compass/pie" and I added " @import "compass/css3/pie" " to my style and It's not working. Do I need do somethingelse?

Comment: @quatermain Sorry, I don't know Compass, PIE or Rails well enough to know from just looking. First look at the source to check that the PIE.htc behaviour file has been loaded with a `text/x-component` content-type. Then check that the *rendered* CSS/JS files contain the relevant PIE code.

Comment: Thank you @Blowski for you interest. Is it better dev. tools in IE as default Developer Tools?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12035/discussion-between-blowski-and-quatermain)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck using compass to install pie. I just downloaded pie from [css3pie.com](http://css3pie.com), put the PIE.htc file in the stylesheets directory under assets, and put the following inside of my _base.scss file that I import into all my individual stylesheets.

```
@import "compass/css3/pie";

$pie-behavior: url("/assets/PIE.htc");
$pie-base-class: pie-element;

.pie-element {
  @include pie-element(relative);
}
```

I then use @extend .pie-element.

Hope this helps.